# how to connect to docker container from another docker container through ssh

Tags: deployment, ssh, docker

I need realize connection from one docker container to another.
`docker run -ti` is not the solution, I need certainly ssh access.

How to implement this communication type?
Can you help?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/

Answer (score 1):

docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service –from  Wolfgang Fahl